# User Login issue for users, its only allowing admin to login from front-end its buffering with username or password is wrong for other users

Tags: users, login

i used user login form from craft document https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/login-form.html

Comment: Not sure I'm following. Can you clarify the exact problem(s) you're having?

Comment: from front end login page only admins can login if users tried to login then it will redirect to login page only with wrong user name or password msg